# Site crawling/indexing issues caused by link structure?

Tags: html, seo, search-engine

I'm doing SEO-type work for a client with many diverse site properties-- none of which were built by myself. One of them in particular, to which I'm linking [**here**](http://goo.gl/hycgkT), appears to be having issues being indexed by search engines. Interestingly, I've tried multiple sitemap generator tools and they too seem to have problems indexing the site; although the site is made up of only a few pages and external links, the sitemap tools-- and I suspect search engines-- are only seeing the homepage itself and nothing else.

In Google webmaster tools, I'm seeing a couple crawl errors (404) relating to home/index.html but nothing else. Also, in Google Analytics, over 80% of the traffic is direct-- i.e. not search traffic-- which seems alarming. The site has been live for about a month, and is being promoted by various sources. Even searching Google using the domain name itself doesn't bring the homepage up in results (!), let alone any related keywords.

My ultimate question is whether or not there appears to be any glaring issues with the code that might prevent proper indexing. I'm noticing that the developer chose to structure the navigation by naming directories, i.e. linking to "home/index.html," "team/index.html," "about/index.html" etc. when it seems optimal to be naming the HTML file itself, i.e. "team.html" and "about.html." Could this be part of the problem?

Thanks for any insight here.

Comment: html markup has a lot of errors, stray html tag (looks 3 html tags declared) http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.raisetheriver.org%2Fhome%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: ugh--good point. I didn't even run the validator I was so focused on indexing. This markup needs some tidying up for sure...

Comment: yes, to find links in page crawler must parse html, it will compensate bad markup to some extent but there is a limit how much guessing it can do

Comment: right makes sense; do you think structuring the navigation in the way I mentioned-- i.e. "section-name/index.html" poses a problem too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two major issues here.

First issue is the root http://www.raisetheriver.org/ has a meta refresh that redirects the page to http://www.raisetheriver.org/home/index.html

Google recommends against using meta refresh, 301 redirects should be used if you want to redirect pages.  However I recommend against redirecting the root home page to another page, as a websites home page is expected to be the root.

The second issue is that all the pages on the site are blocked from being indexed in Google as they have the following code in the source code: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` which instructs search engines not to index the page.

Correct these issue and the site will be able to get indexed in Google and sitemap generators will be able to crawl the site.

Comment: oh yikes-- thanks moobot. I can't believe there's a noindex there; need to have a chat with the developer. I also noticed the redirect and figured that could be a problem. thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

Having sub directories for the pages won't be an issue to web crawler because even large site like Amazon, Ebay and many other have sub directory align pages.

This error occurred that due to your sitemap.xml or sitemap.html might contain invalid or broken links and have been indexed to Google. And you can generate sitemap using this site http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ even I am using this and works perfectly.

And please check manually all directories and pages in your cpanel is working or not. If find any any invalid link you may be able to fix it.

Comment: thanks for the feedback; I actually manually created a sitemap to submit to Google, but as moobot pointed out above the larger issue is due to a "noindex" directive.